# How to check if Firestore query is empty or document that I am trying to fetch does not exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch a document in Cloud Firestore based on a field ID, but that ID cannot be found, how to check that because it is throwing an error?

```
    getMenu = () => {
    try {
        this.setState({
            loading_menu: true
        })

        var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants_menu')
            .where("rest_id", "==", this.getSelected.rest_id)
            .limit(this.state.limit_menu)

        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
            var menu = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } });
            var lastVisibleMenu = menu[menu.length - 1].rest_id;
            this.setState({
                menu: menu,
                lastVisibleMenu: lastVisibleMenu,
                loading_menu: false,
            });
        }));
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("SOMETHING HAPPENED, WE COULD NOT FETCH restaurants_menu:  ", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap it in a try/catch `onSnapshot` returns a promise or observable (I am not sure which one) but for both you can intercept errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your snapshot handler is getting invoked, then there was no error.  Just check the length of the `querySnapshot.docs` array to find out how many documents were matched by the query.  It's not an error to match 0 documents - you should expect that could be the case.

If you want to handle possible errors, you should be passing more than a single snapshot handler.  The documentation for [onSnapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html#onsnapshot) suggests that you should pass a single observer object with various properties for each type of handler function.

```
ref.onSnapshot({
    next: snapshot => {
        // your snapshot handler code
    },
    error: error => {
        // your error handling code
    }
})
```

Comment: I dont understand when you say that I have to use more than one snapshot handler. Can you use my code to implement what you saying?

Comment: @bmm It just means `next` hanler and `error` handler. The two handlers given in the code. There is even a third handler you can add `complete`. Take a look at the documentation and read up on handling observables and/or promises.

Comment: My code shows the template for passing two handlers, one for snapshots and another for errors.  It comes from the API documentation I linked to.  Use this pattern, or you won't be able to check for errors.  But as I said, getting 0 documents back from a query is not an error.  Just check the length of the docs array for that.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, I think the problem is somewhere else, but i will eitherway try to use the handlers the way you said.

Comment: For listeners, the only errors you should expect will come from violation of security rules.  Network errors are simply retried internally by the SDK, and your code will never know about that.

Comment: sorry I didnt write it properly, I meant I found the problem, it is located totally somewhere else not in the query. The problem is that I am trying to display something in the render method {menu} and this does not return anything because there is not anything in the database.